# How to not waste time waiting for many network-bound tasks in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, networking, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

In my Python console app, I have a simple for loop that looks like this:

```
for package in page.packages:
    package.load()
    # do stuff with package
```

Every time it's called, `package.load()` makes a series of HTTP requests. Since `page.packages` typically contains thousands of packages, the `load()` call is becoming a substantial bottleneck for my app.

To speed things up, I've thought about using the `multiprocessing` module to do parallelization, but that would still waste a lot of resources because the threads are network-bound, not CPU-bound: instead of having 1 thread waiting around doing nothing, you'd have 4 of them. Is it possible to use asynchrony instead to somehow just use one/a few threads, but make sure they're never waiting around for the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asyncio is an excellent fit for this, but you will need to convert your HTTP loading code `Package.load` to async using something like aiohttp. For example:

```
async def load(self):
    with self._session.get(self.uri, params) as resp:
        data = resp.read()  # etc
```

The sequential loop you've had previously would be expressed as:

```
async def load_all_serial(page):
    for package in page.packages:
        await package.load()
```

But now you also have the option to start the downloads in parallel:

```
async def load_all_parallel(page):
    # just create tasks, do not await them yet
    tasks = [package.load() for package in page.packages]
    # now let them run, and wait until all have been completed
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Calling either of these async functions from synchronous code is as simple as:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(load_all_parallel(page))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried using aiohttp and the speed gains have blown me away. Although I knew this was a problem beforehand, it's unbelievable how much time my app was taking up just by sitting around.